# Заменить элемент в списке если не проходят по условию (в одну строку)

Tags: python

```
spisok = ["text", "150", "200", "text", "123", "text", "slovo1"]
```

Требуется вывести этот список и заменить строки на `"None"`, если они не могут быть преобразованы в число. Есть такое код:

```
for i in range(len(spisok)):
    if not spisok[i].isdigit():
        spisok[i] = 'None'

print(spisok)
```

Нужно его записать в одну строку.

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/wOf72c

```
a = ["text", "150", "200", "text", "123", "text", "slovo1"]
a = [x if x.isdigit() else None for x in a]
print(a)
```

Comment: Та подправил сам уже, спасибо :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, исправил)

Answer (score 2):

По приколу можно ещё индексирование использовать вместо тернарного оператора:

```
a = ["text", "150", "200", "text", "123", "text", "slovo1"]
a = [('None',x)[x.isdigit()] for x in a]
print(a)
# ['None', '150', '200', 'None', '123', 'None', 'None']
```